# Solve $\cos(5y) + \cos(3y) +\cos(y) = 0.5$ for real $y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Well $\cos(3y)=\cos(y+2y)=\cos(y)\cos(2y)-\sin(y)\sin(2y)$. That's all I got. I've tried putting it in the equation but it doesn't seem to work out. How to solve this?

Comment: You want to write $\cos{kx}$ as a polynomial entirely in $\cos{x}$, and leave $\sin$ out of it.

Comment: how do I put Ant's edit back again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly   $y\ne n\pi\implies\sin y\ne0$  for any integer $n$

Multiply either sides by $2\sin y,$ ([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro) shows why $2\sin y$ was chosen as the multiplier)

and using [Werner Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html) $2\cos A\sin B=\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B)$

to find $\displaystyle\sin6y=\sin y$

Now if $\sin x=\sin A,x=m\pi+(-1)^mA$ where $m$ is any integer

Don't forget to eliminate the extraneous root $y=m\pi$

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to get rid of $\cos(2y)=\cos(y+y)=\cos y\cos y-\sin y\sin y$.

$\cos(5y)=\cos(3y+2y)=\cos(3y)\cos(2y)-\sin(3y)\sin(2y)$

So by doing these kind of substitutions you should get an equation in $\cos^n(x)$.

Or you can skip and look here: http://www.analyzemath.com/trigonometry/trigonometric_formulas.html at point $15$.

Good luck!